# Configuring IIS for strong ETags only (“w/“ weak broke caching)

Tags: iis, caching, iframe, browser-cache, etag

W/eak ETags -> No Caching

Yesterday I published a single index.html and index.hash.js file to an IIS website. The generated ETags had a “W/“ prefix which I learned meant they were weak and it broke caching from our other site such that both files were downloaded with every request.

I rebundled & published the same exact code and the new ETag didn’t have the “Weak” prefix correcting the caching issue and all is back to normal.

That’s a pretty important difference that I seem to have no control over (or was even aware of). Anyone have suggestions on how to ensure the ETags generated by IIS are always “strong”?

Thanks so much!

James

Comment: Weak `ETags` make sites faster, not slower. They're a way of indicating that responses don't have to be byte-for-byte identical to be considered that same from a caching perspective, and their main use is to allow responses to be GZipped. The question is why, in your case, their use "broke caching", so you may want to include more details on what you mean by that.

Comment: ETag generated by IIS has two parts: Filetimestamp:ChangeNumber. If you want to generate strong ETag, you can add ETag headers in HTTP response headers module to make IIS force generate.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqlfX.png

Comment: Thanks, I have a site that loads another in an IFrame. If the ETag is prefixed with W/ it loads the content and it's scripts every single time you open the IFrame (same url, everything). If you (seemingly randomly) get a strong ETag the content is cached until it changes.

Comment: Clients don't do anything with `ETags` other than pass them to the server, so the question is why the server is returning a `200` (with the full response) rather than a `304` when it gets a weak `ETag` in the `If-None-Match` header. There is likely some bug or misconfiguration in the server that is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my Azure Devops build machine was running UTC, the web server PST. Files deployed to the web server were "modified" several hours into the future and the generated Etags were always "weak" until the clock caught up. By setting the timezone on the build server the artifacts had PST timestamps and all was resolved.

Thanks to everyone who contributed their insights!